# Slow ScrollView performance in Xamarin.Forms and WinPhone Silverlight

Tags: xamarin, windows-phone-8.1, xamarin.forms

I´m facing a bad performance using all sort of layouts (e.g. StackLayout, Grid) inside a ScrollView specifically on the WP SL platform. On the other platforms (Android and iOS) the performance is way better using the same layout. I´m using the latest stable version of Xamarin.Forms (2.3.1.114) at the moment. Has anyone faced this issue too?

Thanks.

UPDATE: Code sample added to better understanding. The layout itself is not complex.

```
    <ScrollView>
      <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Black" Padding="5" Spacing="20" >
       <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="User name:" />
        <Label Text="{Binding LoggedInUser}" />
       </StackLayout>
       <StackLayout>
        <Label FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Gray" Text="Help" />
        <BoxView HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="Gray" HorizontalOptions="Fill" />
        <Label FontSize="Small" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Gray" Text="Please, send an email to xxx@example.com" />  
       </StackLayout>
      </StackLayout>
   </ScrollView>
```

Comment: No, it just works great. Maybe you want to post a sample of your slow performing layout.

Comment: @Rohit it happens in almost every page and mostly they are not complex. The scroll view will always slows down when it reaches the beginning or end of the page giving a bad experience to the user.